# Implementation method selection for sparse constrained linear least squares or quadratic programming

Tags: constrained-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I need to slove one optimization problem of quadratic programming. The number of optimization variables is about 16,000. The constraints include equality constraints and inequality constraints.

I have no such practical experiences before.
There are are three choices for the probelm after reading some materials:

```
 active set method,     
 interior point method
 augmented Lagrangian method
```

I need implement the optimization algorithm on my own.

Active set method is not suitable for such problem size.
Interior point method is fast but difficult to implement from the link:
[rank-deficient NNLS](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14228/rank-deficient-nnls/14236#14236)
*A first order method (Augmented Lagrangian, ADMM, split Bregman, etc.) These are possible to implement yourself without needing to use a packaged library.*
So augmented Lagrangian method will be my choice.
How about my analysis?
Most materials I find is about augmented Lagrangian method with equality constraints. Can you recommand any links or materials on augmented Lagrangian method with inequality constraints?

Comment: Why implement such a method yourself when there is great software already out there!?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  The optimization solver need run on mobile phone. I hope to implement the solver myslef based on Eigen library. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I have no experience with phone apps, sorry.